# Will a 120Hz monitor work with Thunderbolt?

Tags: display, thunderbolt

Will a 2011 Mac with Thunderbolt run a 120Hz monitor?

I ask because I'm considering switching my desktop from a 24" iMac 2.8 ATI to a 2011 Mac mini AMD and want to pick the best monitor.

Answer (score 1):

If the monitor works with whatever adapter you want to use (Mini DisplayPort to DVI, etc.), then it should work fine on the Thunderbolt port.

When it comes to monitors, Thunderbolt isn't special: it's just like DisplayPort.